# react js form inputs using eval?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eval

I have a form with 58 inputs so, i wanted to do this dinamically, having this fields with the values i need(name, placeholder, value)...I've mapped throw an array of strings and got ***name*** and ***placeholder*** ok BUT when I tried to obtain the ***value*** I've read a bit and found the *eval function*...and in deed it solved my problem...but then react js sent me an 'eval can be harmful' warning so...

Question 1: In my case is really eval harmfull?How can I avoid that in my way of being a by the book programmer?

Question2: In which other way can I obtain my value's value?

now I show a piece of my code...:

```js
{variables.map((variable, index) =>
  <div className="form-group">
    <input
      key={index}
      type="text"
      name={variable}
      className="form-control"
      placeholder={variable}
      onChange={handleInputchange}
      value={eval(variable)}
    />
  </div>
)}
```

where variables is an array of strings

thanks for your time

Comment: heheh "by the book programmer"

Comment: Where do the variable values come from? Globals in `window`? You could use `{window[variable]}` then, but it's still not great design.

Comment: first i've tried to convert the variable' s name into string with no result, so, i had to create a new array of strings and did as I said before..I am looking for the best way to do this. If not many inputs weren t the case wuld be no problem, but I have 58 inputs...I suspect of this 'cause intuition told me that should be a better way to do this without creating a new array...I can tell you for sure that{window[variable]} is not a fix to my issue cause i can not obtain inputs'value this way but eval() way

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to have an object if possible for the fields, that way you can access the values by key like this:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const Test = () => {
    const [formData, setFields] = useState({
        field1: '',
        field2: '',
        field3: '',
    });

    const handleChange = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setFields(prev => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.taget.value }));
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {Object.keys(formData).map(fieldName => (
                <div className="form-group" key={fieldName}>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        name={fieldName}
                        placeholder={fieldName}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        value={formData[fieldName]}
                    />
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Test;
```

If you must have the initial fields as an Array i'd probably just use reduce to turn the initial form data into an object like this:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const fields = ['field 1', 'field 2', 'field 3'];
const initialState = fields.reduce((acc, field) => ({ ...acc, [field]: field }), {});

const Test = () => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialState);

    const handleChange = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setFormData(prev => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.taget.value }));
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {Object.keys(formData).map(fieldName => (
                <div className="form-group" key={fieldName}>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        name={fieldName}
                        placeholder={fieldName}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        value={fields[fieldName]}
                    />
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Test;
```